# Regex that matches all week day's name in a string

Tags: python, regex, match

I want to match every week day in a string where all words are comma separated.

Examples:
"mon, thu, fry" should be matched
"mon, tue, sat" should be matched
"" should not be matched
"mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun" should be matched
"foo, bar" should not be matched

I came up with this regex but it matches only the string containing ALL week days:

```
^(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)$
```

How can I match them "indipendently"?

I am using python3

Comment: You can use: [`^(?:mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(?:\s*,\s*(?:mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/jdqmCS/2)

Comment: What happens if a string has days mixed with non day words, e.g. `mon, foo` ?

Comment: Perhaps, `^(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(,\s*(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun))*$`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I should then handle that as an invalid string in my code. So the regex should not match anything... in an ideal world

Comment: @refex - Check anubhava's comment. It handles the scenario which Tim is describing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the ability to use the newer **[`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/)** module, you could use a [**recursive approach**](https://regex101.com/r/jdqmCS/3):

```
^((?:mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(?:, )?)(?1)*$'
```

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import regex as re

string = """
mon, tue, fri
mon, tue, sat
mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun
foo, bar
mon
tue
wed
mon, wed
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^((?:mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun)(?:, )?)(?1)*$')
days = list(filter(lambda x: rx.match(x), string.split("\n")))
print(days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than give you the direct answer, I'll try the teach you to fish approach.

Use an interactive regular expression facility (such as http://pythex.org), enter your tests strings first, then iterate on your regular expression string until all of the test strings match to your specification.

I'll give you a hint that you'll need to use a capture group and possibly a quantifier.

The interactive facility usually has a "regular expression cheatsheet" you can consult to give you ideas.

Good luck with your homework!